# A Handler with a 15 second delay only works accurately when the device is on charge

Tags: android, handler

I'm creating an application where I want a Handler to send an http request every 15 second. The problem is, that while my device (huawei watch 2) is on chare, the Handler works as supposed to, but when I take the watch off the charger, the 15 second is changes between 15 and 40 seconds. Is there a problem with my implementation? I'm not passing any Runnable to the Handler, since there is only a little work to do. I have a `SensorHelper` class, which just gets the heart rate value. In the request I'm sending a custom message object as JSON.

`MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {

    private static ConnectionService mService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS},
                    1);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectionService.class);
        this.startService(intent);
        this.bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Enables Always-on
        setAmbientEnabled();
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            ConnectionService.LocalBinder binder = (ConnectionService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getServiceInstance();
            try {
                sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        }
    };

    public static void sendMessage(String message) {
        mService.sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

`ConnectionService` in order to avoid my application to go into DOZE mode:

```
public class ConnectionService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private static SensorHelper sensorHelper;
    private static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    public static final MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public ConnectionService getServiceInstance() {
            return ConnectionService.this;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (sensorHelper == null) {
            sensorHelper = new SensorHelper(this);
        }
        super.onCreate();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("ASD")
                .setContentText("ASD")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        startForeground(1337, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        Message msg = new Message("HR", message);
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, msg.toJson());

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://104.248.32.100/")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

`SensorHelper` in order to get the heart rate value, and post it:

```
public class SensorHelper implements SensorEventListener {

    private String sensorValue = "normal";
    private static Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int delay = 15000;

    public SensorHelper(Context context) {
        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor heartRateSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, heartRateSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                sendMessage();
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            }
        }, delay);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE) {
            sensorValue = String.valueOf(event.values[0]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged (Sensor sensor,int i){
    }

    private String getSensorValue() {
        return sensorValue;
    }

    private void sendMessage() {
        MainActivity.sendMessage(getSensorValue());
    }
}
```

Is there any mistakes I'm making, while the Handler is not working correctly? Is passing a Runnable necessary to create a new Thread? As far as is read, the Handler is creating a new Thread

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem, with a lot of applications that run on the background while the device is not charging. The problem is Android's battery optimization.

The solution is pretty simple, you have to disable your app's battery optimization by going to **Settings > Battery > Battery optimization** (The path varies by manufacturer).

Some manufacturers also add extra measures to optimize battery by making timed tasks proc less often, so check out for extra settings that might affect this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: all gestures, optimizations and other services are disabled :/